# Clarification of dyadic expansion notation in Billingsley's Probability and Measure

Tags: probability, measure-theory, notation

I have found plenty of questions regarding this section of the book but none regarding my specific query. This is what the book describes as a *dyadic expansion*:

For a mapping $F$ from $\Omega=(0,1]$ into itself given by $$F\omega=\begin{Bmatrix}
2\omega & \mbox{if } 0< \omega\leqslant\frac{1}{2} \\ 
2\omega-1 & \mbox{if } \frac{1}{2}< \omega\leqslant1 
\end{Bmatrix} $$ and $$d_1(\omega)=\begin{Bmatrix}
0 & \mbox{if } 0< \omega\leqslant\frac{1}{2} \\ 
1 & \mbox{if } \frac{1}{2}< \omega\leqslant1 
\end{Bmatrix} $$ and $d_i(\omega)=d_1(F^{i-1}\omega)$.

My question is, how is the exponent on $F$ to be interpreted? The way I read it, $d_i$ with $i = 1$ would mean that $d_1 = d_1(F^{0}\omega) = d_1(1)$ which obviously contradicts the definition just given above. What am I missing here?

(lifted the nice notation from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117490/dyadic-expansion-proof))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a function composition.

$F^0(\omega)=\omega$ and $F^{i+1}(\omega) = F\circ F^i(\omega)$.